# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/catalina/LifecycleException

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jnlp, embedded-tomcat-8

I am working on a project which looks to embed tomcat in a java web application.
I wish to convert this application into java web start so that it can be deployed and anyone who downloads the application can use the application on the embedded server without having to download tomcat.
The problem I am facing is that the code runs perfectly when I run it on eclipse but when I convert it into a downloadable file which on starting shows the error I have mentioned in my title.
I had an error previously which said... java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/catalina/Context 
I fixed this by using the Catalina jar file as one of my resources href in the jnlp file.
This LifecycleException though according to my knowledge is a part of Catalina.jar.
Please do help in solving my error or at least point me in the right direction to solve it.
I'm running the code using a maven project on Eclipse IDE.
Thanks!

```
package com.N.VJ;

import java.io.File;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;

public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) throws LifecycleException, 
InterruptedException, ServletException {

String docBase = "src/main/webapp/";

Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
String webPort = System.getenv("PORT");
    if(webPort == null || webPort.isEmpty()) {
        webPort = "8088";
    }
    tomcat.setPort(Integer.valueOf(webPort));

tomcat.addWebapp("/", new File(docBase).getAbsolutePath());
System.out.println("configuring app with basedir: " + new File("./" + 
docBase).getAbsolutePath());

tomcat.start();
tomcat.getServer().await();
}

}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.tom1</groupId>
<artifactId>cat1</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>cat1 Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
<version>${tomcat.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
<version>${tomcat.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
<version>${tomcat.version}</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
<finalName>cat1</finalName>

<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <archive>
        <manifest>
            <mainClass>com.tom1.cat1.App</mainClass>
        </manifest>
    </archive>
</configuration>
</plugin>        
 <plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <port>${tomcat.port}</port>
    <path>/</path>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>tomcat-run</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>exec-war-only</goal>
      </goals>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <configuration>
        <path>/</path>
        <port>${tomcat.port}</port>
        <attachArtifactClassifierType>war</attachArtifactClassifierType>

<mainClass>org.apache.tomcat.maven.runner.Tomcat8RunnerCli</mainClass>
        <extraDependencies>
          <extraDependency>
            <groupId>com.nitorcreations</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat8-war-runner</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
          </extraDependency>
        </extraDependencies>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
      <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-util</artifactId>
      <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-coyote</artifactId>
      <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-api</artifactId>
      <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
      <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
      <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-jasper-el</artifactId>
      <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-el-api</artifactId>
      <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
      <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-tribes</artifactId>
      <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-catalina-ha</artifactId>
      <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-annotations-api</artifactId>
      <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-juli</artifactId>
      <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
      <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-log4j</artifactId>
      <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>tomcat-run</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>exec-war-only</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <configuration>             
          <warRunDependencies>
            <warRunDependency>
              <dependency>
                <groupId>com.tom1</groupId>
                <artifactId>cat1</artifactId>
                <version>4</version>
                <type>war</type>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
<type>maven-plugin</type>
</dependency>
              <contextPath>/</contextPath>
            </warRunDependency>
          </warRunDependencies>
          <enableNaming>true</enableNaming>
          <extraDependencies>
            <extraDependency>
              <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
              <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
              <version>10.1.3.1</version>
            </extraDependency>
            <extraDependency>
              <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
              <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
              <version>1.4</version>
            </extraDependency>
          </extraDependencies>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
<properties>
<tomcat.version>8.0.48</tomcat.version>
</properties>
</project>
```

JNLP FILE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+"
 codebase="http://localhost:8080/TCApp" 

href="http://localhost:8080/TCApp/SO.jnlp">
<information>
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <vendor>Noel Joseph</vendor>
    <homepage href="http://localhost:8080/TCApp/display.html" />
    <description> Hello World</description>
</information>

<security>
    <all-permissions />
</security>

<resources>
    <j2se version="1.4+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="SO.jar" />
    <jar href="catalina-6.0.29.jar" />
    <jar href="catalina-ha-6.0.29.jar" />
</resources>    

<application-desc main-class="com.N.VJ.App"/>

</jnlp>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey guys fixed the error. 
Was welcomed by new errors but fixed them to.
It was rather simple wonder why i didn't consider it before.
So all i did was add jar href=" whichever jar was necessary ".
So according to what i understood the packaging done when we jar a file in eclipse it doesn't really package all the necessary jars or maybe it does but they're not useful during run time as that's when the main class calls for the necessary jars and theyre missing.
By adding these necessary jars in href they're called during run time and TADA your problems solved.

My JNLP file looked like this at the end.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+"
 codebase="http://localhost:8080/TCApp" 

href="http://localhost:8080/TCApp/SO.jnlp">
<information>
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <vendor>Noel Joseph</vendor>
    <homepage href="http://localhost:8080/TCApp/display.html" />
    <description> Hello World</description>
</information>

<security>
    <all-permissions />
</security>

<resources>
    <j2se version="1.4+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="New3.jar" main="true"/>
    <jar href="tomcat-catalina-9.0.10.jar" />
    <jar href="javax.servlet.jar" />
    <jar href="javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar" />
    <jar href="tomcat-util-9.0.10.jar" />
    <jar href="tomcat-util-scan-9.0.10.jar" />
    <jar href="tomcat-juli-9.0.10.jar" />
    <jar href="tomcat-coyote-9.0.10.jar" />
    <jar href="tomcat-api-9.0.10.jar" />
    <jar href="tomcat-jni-9.0.10.jar" />
    <jar href="tomcat-jsp-api-9.0.10.jar" />
    <jar href="commons-logging-1.2.jar" />
    <property name="sun.java2d.noddraw"
        value="true"/>

</resources>    

<application-desc main-class="com.NO.JO.App"/>

</jnlp>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution and welcome to SO!. One comment: Please note, that java web start has been deprecated and will be removed in future Java releases. So this can only be a temp solution...

Comment: I'm interning at a company and this is my project here so it really doesn't matter to me. Thanks for the info though will let them know.